# How to parse MSsql string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, management-studio-express

Help please 
I need to get from this string

```
SELECT value 
FROM STRING_SPLIT('<166>%ASA-6-302013: Built outbound TCP connection 322558458 for ethKASSY:192.168.1.13/10001 (10.21.8.13/10001) to ethASK_EXT_TSSM:10.43.8.24/5508 (192.168.1.10/30475) ', ' ') 
where value in('ethKASSY:192.168.1.13/10001')
```

Ip address 192.168.1.13 and port 192.168.1.13

Maybe Anybody knows?

Comment: What you need as the output.

Comment: I need TCP, 192.168.1.13/10001,  192.168.1.10/30475

Comment: something like this - SELECT LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(value ,'(',''),')',''),'ethKASSY:',''))
FROM STRING_SPLIT('<166>%ASA-6-302013: Built outbound TCP connection 322558458 for 
ethKASSY:192.168.1.13/10001 (10.21.8.13/10001) to ethASK_EXT_TSSM:10.43.8.24/5508 (192.168.1.10/30475) ', ' ') 
Where value LIKE '%192.168.1%'